# Github integration on AppHarbor not working

Tags: appharbor

I can't seem to get Github integration working with my application on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/).  I don't see any errors in the build details, it's just a blank txt in the details... and it never switches to active with the status staying as the red no circle.

I followed the instructions on configuring my github repository with slug and token in the service hooks.  The application deploys fine when I push directly to app harbor git.

Is there a trick or a gotcha that I might be forgetting?

Comment: So the code is being sent to appharbor and built, but simply not deployed? If you click through to the build, what does the log say? (not the build output, just the log)

Comment: 4/29/12 11:42 PM: Received notification, queuing build
4/29/12 11:42 PM: Starting build
4/29/12 11:42 PM: Downloading source
4/29/12 11:42 PM: Build failed: An error occured while downloading the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a private repository you have to add the `apphb` user on Github as a collaborator.

Answer (score 1):

For future references, another thing to note is, that it only push the code when it gets commited. Therefor, if you commit, then set up github, you will need to commit again in order to get it pushed.